# Comparison object being invocable as const

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

When I try to run the following code, both clang (6.0) and g++ (8) with -std=c++17 give me a static_assert error:

```
#include <set>
struct A {};

struct ProcessComparator { inline bool operator()(const A&, const A&) { return true; } };

int main(void)
{
    std::set<A, ProcessComparator> A_Set;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

g++ 8

> /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_tree.h:457:7: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 'is_invocable_v' "comparison object must be invocable as const"

clang 6.0

> /usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_tree.h:457:21: error: static assertion failed: comparison object must be invocable as const

Putting a const as part of the operator() signature fixes this problem:

```
#include <set>

struct A {};

/* Add const as part of the operator's signature */
struct ProcessComparator { inline bool operator()(const A&, const A&) const { return true; } };

int main(void)
{
    std::set<A, ProcessComparator> A_Set;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Meanwhile with std=c++14 the error goes away in both clang and g++.

My question is what changed in c++17 for this to now give an error and why does the const here matter?

The const only guarantees that every object declared inside the ProcessComparator class doesn't get modified (aside from those with mutable), so why is this a requirement?

---

This is the source code from the source code where the static assert fails:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
      static_assert(__is_invocable<_Compare&, const _Key&, const _Key&>{},
      "comparison object must be invocable with two arguments of key type");
# if __cplusplus >= 201703L
      // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
      // 2542. Missing const requirements for associative containers
      static_assert(is_invocable_v<const _Compare&, const _Key&, const _Key&>,
      "comparison object must be invocable as const");
# endif // C++17
#endif // C++11
```

A new static_assert was added where the Comparison object was changed from just `_Compare&<` to `const _Compare&` and `is_invocable` to `is_invocable_v`, although that, from what I can understand, is just to gain inline and constexpr [as seen here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable)

---

I've found [this](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2542) link, based on the source code comment, but I still cannot understand **why** this is required.

Comment: Comparison operators should've always been const. This unspoken rule is now being actively enforced.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ok, but why should they be const? Are there any benefits or was there some historical reason for it to happen?

Comment: Because an instance of the comparator class is a part of the container, and you cannot invoke a method of a `const` class instance unless the method is `const`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That does make sense, but then why did c++14 allow this? Is it because there were no const methods of set in c++14 or was it purely an overlook?

Comment: Well, it was only "allowed" in a sense that if you used class methods which make use of the comparator class only on mutable instances of the container, it would still work. But attempting to use them on `const` containers will still fail, because it would be fundamentally ill-formed. As such, this is strictly enforcing `const`-correctness. Which is always a good thing; and I see very little benefit in wasting time figuring out why it was allegedly still "allowed" in C++14. It's completely irrelevant. Any code that did that was broken, and should be fixed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Ah, ok, I wanted to know why it was still 'allowed' in c++14, in case there was some reason other than just an overlook, as for example a guarantee that Comparator would only be called in methods that modified the container or something alike. Also would you like to post this as an answer?

Comment: Note that both of your compilers were using the same standard library implementation, so the synchronization shouldn’t be surprising.

Comment: It was merely an oversight. It wasn't allowed for any deliberate reason

Answer (score 17):

Make operator const, as it should be (no mutable state allowed):

```
struct ProcessComparator { inline bool operator()(const A&, const A&) const { return true; } };
```

If you run this comparator in parallel across threads, constness is nice for safety. It also prevents potentially problem-causing side-effects and allows the compiler to optimize things more, by default. If the stdlib allowed the operator to be non-const, it should also assume that there is some state there being modified (non-const) and thus that access might not be thread-safe or that it might not make copies willy-nilly (parallel access).

While the compiler probably can figure this it out on its own (but only if inlined), the library enforces this to help you write more correct and idiomatic code.

**Update**

A case where it could happen if you try to be clever and cache pointers to objects in the comparison operator to do quicker comparison if same objects are being compared several times (see f.ex. less than in many sorting ops).

Answer (score 3):

This is not really an answer, but an illustrative example:

Suppose you have a routine that tests if your set contains a particular value:

```
template <typename T>
bool contains(const std::set<T> &s, const T& value)
{ return s.find(value) != s.end(); }
```

If your comparison functor cannot be invoked as const, then this will fail to compile with a horrible error message. (even in C++11 and 14)