# Get 'is_invocable' errorr for set comparator

Tags: c++, set

I try to create a type for a set with a custom comparator:

```cpp
typedef unsigned char uchar;

struct hash_comparator {
    bool operator()(const uchar *p1, const uchar *p2) {
        return (memcmp(p1, p2, NUM_BYTES) < 0);
    };
};

typedef  std::set<uchar *, hash_comparator> hash_set;
```

and later use it like this.

```cpp
hash_set m_sKnownHashes;
 ...
hash_set::const_iterator it; 
for (it = m_sKnownHashes.begin(); it != m_sKnownHashes.end(); ++it) {
     ...
}
```

When i compile this code i get an error which i don't understand:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12/include/g++-v12/set:60,
                 from CycleFinderH.h:6,
                 from CycleFinderH.cpp:11:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12/include/g++-v12/bits/stl_tree.h: In instantiation of ‘static const _Key& std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_S_key(_Const_Link_type) [with _Key = unsigned char*; _Val = unsigned char*; _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<unsigned char*>; _Compare = hash_comparator; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char*>; _Const_Link_type = const std::_Rb_tree_node<unsigned char*>*]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12/include/g++-v12/bits/stl_tree.h:1953:36:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator  std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::_M_lower_bound(_Link_type, _Base_ptr, const _Key&) [with _Key = unsigned char*; _Val = unsigned char*; _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<unsigned char*>; _Compare = hash_comparator; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char*>; iterator = std::_Rb_tree<unsigned char*, unsigned char*, std::_Identity<unsigned char*>, hash_comparator, std::allocator<unsigned char*> >::iterator; _Link_type = std::_Rb_tree_node<unsigned char*>*; _Base_ptr = std::_Rb_tree_node_base*]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12/include/g++-v12/bits/stl_tree.h:2533:36:   required from ‘std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::find(const _Key&) [with _Key = unsigned char*; _Val = unsigned char*; _KeyOfValue = std::_Identity<unsigned char*>; _Compare = hash_comparator; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char*>; iterator = std::_Rb_tree<unsigned char*, unsigned char*, std::_Identity<unsigned char*>, hash_comparator, std::allocator<unsigned char*> >::iterator]’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12/include/g++-v12/bits/stl_set.h:795:25:   required from ‘std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::find(const key_type&) [with _Key = unsigned char*; _Compare = hash_comparator; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char*>; iterator = std::_Rb_tree<unsigned char*, unsigned char*, std::_Identity<unsigned char*>, hash_comparator, std::allocator<unsigned char*> >::const_iterator; key_type = unsigned char*]’
CycleFinderH.cpp:172:58:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12/include/g++-v12/bits/stl_tree.h:772:15: error: static assertion failed: comparison object must be invocable as const
  772 |               is_invocable_v<const _Compare&, const _Key&, const _Key&>,
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12/include/g++-v12/bits/stl_tree.h:772:15: note:  ‘std::is_invocable_v<const hash_comparator&, unsigned char* const&, unsigned char* const&>’evaluates to false
make: *** [Makefile:31: CycleFinderH.o] Error 1
```

The line 172 mentioned above is this:

```
hash_set::const_iterator it = m_sKnownHashes.find(pHash);
```

(where `pHash` is a `uchar*`)

What exactly does that error mean?

How do i have to write my `typedef` so it works as i intend?

Comment: It means that your comparator is not a `const` class method.

Comment: Here is the error: `error: static assertion failed: comparison object must be invocable as const`. Do you understand what it means?

Comment: make your member functions `const` by default. Only make them non-const when they need to modify a member

Comment: The dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235355/comparison-object-being-invocable-as-const

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts of the error message that gives hints about the problems.

The first is the assertion message istelf:

```
comparison object must be invocable as const
```

And the second is the check done for the assertion:

```
std::is_invocable_v<const hash_comparator&, ...
```

Note the `const` in `const hash_comparator&`. That means the `hash_comparator` object is constant, and you can only call `const` qualified functions on constant objects.

Simply make the `operator()` function `const` qualified:

```
bool operator()(const uchar *p1, const uchar *p2) const { ... }
//                                                ^^^^^
//                         Added the const keyword here
```

That means the function can be called on constant objects.